# AutoCompleteTextView - Crash When Rotating Device While Popup Window is Visible

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am experiencing a crash whenever I rotate a device while the AutoCompleteTextView dropdown is displayed.

I can recreate this every time by:

1. Tap the AutoCompleteTextView to bring up a dropdown of suggestions
2. Do not make a selection
3. Rotate the device

**Stacktrace:**

```
     Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
```

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="16dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/criteria_text_input_layout"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Name"
    app:errorEnabled="true">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/criteria_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have searched for that exception and it appears this can happen when you use getApplicationContext(), but all my adapters use getContext(). I have also tried dismissing the dropdown on configuration changes, but to no avail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

BadTokenException happens when your popup or dialog is showing and activity is destroyed. That's why we usually close popups and dialogs in onDestroy(). e.g.

```
if(dialog.isShowing()) {
   dialog.dismiss();
}
```

So Add below line in your onDestroy() for AutoCompleteTextView.

```
yourAutoCompleteTextView.dismissDropDown();
```

Comment: Thanks Bali. I tried your suggestions but unfortunately, they did not work. I posted my solution however.

Comment: Turns out I don't have a solution as it introduces an issue restoring state.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is a problem with Samsung devices (which is what I was using to test). I could not find out exactly where the problem was in the code, but I did notice an error in the logs:

```
sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

So I did another search and found that it's a known bug on some Android devices where mView can be null so one of the suggested solutions was to add the following to the manifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

This seems to have fixed my issue.

**EDIT:**
Using this introduces another problem as rotating the device no longer allows me to restore state properly. So I am now back at square one.

**EDIT #2:**
Seems this problem happens during restoring of state of the TextInputLayout and AutoCompleteTextView. Another solution is to disable saving of state by adding the following to the view(s):

```
    android:saveEnabled="false"
```

By adding this and removing the configChanges above allows me to restore state as I was expecting.

Comment: did you find a SO issue related to this state restoration problem? I have the exact same issue and I wonder if someone has created a dedicated issue for it.

Comment: Hi @guillaume-tgl. No I haven't. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I'm using your workaround of setting `android:saveEnabled` to false